# Orbit such that distance from Earth is always the same as distance from Mars

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, solar-system, satellites

Would it be possible to place a satellite into an orbit such that its distance from Earth and Mars always remained the same? That is the distance between the satellite and Earth and the satellite and Mars was always the same, even though the single  distance between the two planets may vary.

My reason for asking this question is related to using quantum entanglement to communicate instantaneously with Mars through a satellite that always maintains the same distance between itself and the two planets. (Both ideas may be impossible, but I would like to hear from experts if they are.)

Comment: Entanglement doesn't transmit information, and doesn't require that distance be constant.

Answer (score 5):

Possible? Yes, if the satellite has engines and moves to maintain the midpoint position. Along a Keplerian orbit? Not very likely.

We can plot Earth and Mars orbits and calculate the mid-point between them (I have ignored inclination and eccentricity here) over 10 years:
[image]
Basically it follows a spiralling curve that crosses Earth's orbit a fair bit.

However, as Eli pointed out, there is no unique solution. The set of points equidistant to two points is a plane. As Earth and Mars moves there will be a plane (anchored at the points on my curve and orthogonal to the Earth-Mars vector) twirling around. Any trajectory that keeps inside the plane at all times is also equidistant. But I am pretty sure (although I cannot prove it) that there is no Keplerian orbit embedded there.

Answer (score 0):

This could obviously only happen if both planets had the same period but by Kepler’s law
$T^2\propto a^3$.  Thus the planets can have the same period only if they have the same semi-major axis $a$, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps epsilon short of an answer:

Suppose that the only relevant gravitational forces are from the earth (at location $A$), Mars (at location $B$) and the sun (at the origin).  Take the sun's mass and the gravitational constant to be $1$.  Then we have

$$\ddot{A}=-A/r_A^2+M_B(B-A)/r_{AB}^2 \qquad(1)$$
$$\ddot{B}=-B/r_B^2+M_A(A-B)/r_{AB}^2\qquad(2)$$

Now put $$C=(A+B)/2$$ $$X=\Big(M_A(B-A)+M_B(A-B)\Big)/2r_{AB}^2$$.

Then (1) and (2) give

$$\ddot{C}=-A/2r_A^2-B/2r_B^2+X\qquad(3)$$

By contrast, you are requiring

$$\ddot{C}=-C/r_C^2+M_A(C-A)/r_{AC}^2+M_B(C-B)/r_{BC}^2\qquad(4)$$

We have $r_{AC}=r_{BC}=r_{AB}/2$ so you can rewrite (4) as

$$\ddot{C}=-C/r_C^2+4X\qquad(5)$$

I had hoped that (3) and (5) together would yield some condition that is clearly satisfied only under conditions that are both clearly very unlikely and easy to describe (e.g. the two planetary orbits have the same period). I can't quite seem to get there --- it's clear from inspection that you need *some* very special (necessary and sufficient) conditions to make (3) and (5) hold simultaneously but it's not so clear that you can express those conditions in a clear concise way.

Comment: I was considering perhaps a stable orbit that mapped the solar orbit and speed of Mars, BUT positioned exactly opposite its position in orbit.  Would that not maintain a satellite distance to earth and a satellite distance to mars that was always the same?  That is the distance between the satellite and earth and the satellite and Mars would always be the same.  Distance of satellite to earth and distance of satellite to Mars is always equal at any instant in time, even though these distances would change moment by moment.

Comment: @DonMcCann :  At the least, you're going to have to have $C/4r_C^2=A/2r_A^2+B/2r_B^2$ (from (3) and (5)).  In your proposed solution we have $C=-B$ and $r_B=r_C$, so we get $0=A/2r^2+3B/4r_B^2$.  In particular, this implies that the sun, earth and Mars are always colinear, so it certainly won't work with the actual earth and Mars orbits that we've got, though it has a chance to work if you've got a plan to change those orbits.